# Mapping in Clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure

How can I get this piece of code working? It should output four index numbers followed by randomly chosen names from the map.

```
(def persons {0 "name1" 1 "name2" 2 "name3"})
(map #(println (str %1 ": " %2)) (iterate inc 0) (persons (rand-int 3)))
```

Please do not suggest another way, but correct my code if you know how it should be corrected.
It should output something like: 
0: name2, 1: name3, 2: name1

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your code `(persons (rand-int 3))` produces a single random value from map, like "name3" and map treats it like a sequence of characters `(\n \a \m \e \3)`

Just wrap it to call few number of times:

`(repeatedly 4 #(persons (rand-int 3)))`

Right and more cleaner way to do this:

```
(dotimes [i 4]
  (println (str i ":" (rand-nth (vals persons)))))
```

- use `dotimes` instead of `map` if you want side-effects (printing)
- use `(rand-nth (vals persons))` instead of `(persons (rand-int 3))`, ocassionally if your map grows and become 100 elements, `rand-nth` still behaves like expected, while `rand-int` based on map size

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple things to note here:

1. If you want to iterate through a list of things and do some actions that contain side effects (like printing), you should use `doseq` instead of map.
2. If you're dealing with a map, the function you give to `map` or `doseq` should have one argument, a MapEntry -- which is sort of like a 2-item list containing the key and the value. You can use destructuring to get the key and the value.

You could do this:

```
(def persons {0 "name1" 1 "name2" 2 "name3"})

(doseq [[i name] persons]
  (println (str i ": " name)))
```

This doesn't capture the randomness aspect of what you're trying to do, but for that I defer to @mishadoff's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest to "keep it simple" as follows:

```
(def persons {0 "name1" 1 "name2" 2 "name3"})
(let [names       (vals persons)
      names-shuf  (shuffle names)
      idx         (range (count names)) ]
  (doseq [ii idx]
    (println (str ii ": " (nth names-shuf ii)))))
```

which produces:

```
~/clj > lein run
0: name2
1: name1
2: name3
```

or similar (it is different every time).  Note that we use `shuffle` here to ensure exactly 1 result for each name in the map.

Comment: This is the only solution that uses `doseq` properly and also shows a solution that randomly prints names with replacement.

Answer (score 2):

`map` takes a function and one or more collections. You gave it two collections: a lazy sequence (`(iterate inc 0)`) and a string (`(persons (rand-int 3))`). So instead of printing names in a random order, you print the characters in order of a randomly chosen string.

I think you *want* to give it a collection of random names instead. Like think what you want is this:

```
(def persons {0 "name1" 1 "name2" 2 "name3"})
(def randomnames 
  (letfn [(makenames [] 
            (lazy-seq (cons (persons (rand-int 3)) 
                            (makenames))))]
    (makenames)))
(map #(println (str %1 ": " %2)) (take 3 (iterate inc 0)) (take 3 randomnames))
```

The above solution prints random names *with replacement*; doing it without replacement would be more complicated, but you get the idea. The flaw is you're using a random person as the second argument to `map`, when you really want a *collection* of random people, say a vector, with them all scrambled up.